# Recording audio continuously and updating the view

Tags: android, audio, service

I need to record uncompressed audio from the microphone continuously (hours) in an Android app, process the audio and visualise the result in a plot. If the app loses focus, the plotting can (and should) stop, but the recording and the analysis shouldn't.

I'm not sure I got the right steps, so this is the implementation I have in mind:

1. A `RecordActivity` handles the view, in particular plotting the results as they arrive and handling the button presses. A `record` button starts a `RecordService`
2. A `RecordService` service initialises an `android.media.AudioRecord` and on its `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` reads in the buffer, saves it to file and analyses its contents. The result of the analysis is stored.
3. The `RecordService` uses a `PendingIntent` to communicate the results of the analysis to the `RecordActivity`, which updates the plot.
4. When the users presses the stop button, `RecordActivity` kills the service by calling `stopService`.

My questions are:

1. Is it right to use a service for this or can I just use an activity?
2. Is it right to use a started service rather than a bound one?
3. What parts of this process should be handled by a different thread (or even process)? The `AudioRecord`ing? (The analysis obviously depending on the requirements). The entire service?
4. Should the service being a Foreground service?
5. In general, is this structure correct?

Answer (score 0):

1. A `Service` is a good solution, what I don't understand is why you're using a `PendingIntent`. Maybe you should consider using `LocalBroadcast` and normal `Intent`
2. In this case, since the service is bound to the lifecycle of the `Activity`, I suggest to use a bounded `Service` :)
3. Well...it depends. If the AudioRecording implementation has its own thread (as I guess in Android), then it's not strictly required to use a thread. But if you write many datas to filesystem, it could be better to start a thread inside the service and handle your logic there (remember that services are not thread)
4. It depends by your design. If you pause your `Service` logic when the app goes to background, it's not necessary. But if you need your service even when the app goes in background, then it's better to use a foreground `Service`
5. In general, I believe it's a good solution

Comment: Many thanks! About 2., is it really bound to the lifecycle of the activity? I want the service to continue recording even if the screen goes off or the app is in the background. The activity might be killed in that case, right?

Comment: If it's not bound, use a standard service and make it a foreground service. And...Activities are not killed, the are destroyed :)

Comment: That sounds even more gruesome! :-O

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you scared about Services? Yes...they are the worst documented Android area. But...for this kind of project, you should take a look at IntentService source code, or to this [link](http://blog.denevell.org/android-service-handler-tutorial.html). To make a standard service a foreground one, you need just a single command (and yes, of course you need to put an icon for the notification)

Comment: I meant killed vs. destroyed... Never mind... Anyway, yes, having everything in a single activity was good because the result of the analysis are fairly large arrays, and I could just add them. With the analysis in a service, I have to pass results to the activity through an intent, hence making a copy every time.